# _dateparsefailure while parsing tdate with logstash

Tags: date, filter, logstash, elk, logstash-filter

I keep getting _dateparsefailure while parsing date with logstash.

Here is my purpose :

Input field :

```
"r_modify_date" = "20220915161948"
```

Logstash filter configuration :

```
date {match => ["r_modify_date","yyyyMMddHHmmss"] target => ["r_modify_date"]}
```

While searching with Kibana, I keep getting

```
"@modification_date" : [
    "20220915161948"
],
```

in results and also the exception _dateparsefailure in tags.

I just want to transform that date value to this format :

```
"2022-09-15T16:19:48.xxxZ"
```

Any idea how I can do that ?

Comment: Are you renaming [r_modify_date] to [@modification_date], or are you looking at a different field? Is that the only date filter that you have in your configuration?

Comment: Your `date` filter works for me on Logstash `8.2.3` and outputs `2022-09-15T16:19:48Z` as the `r_modify_date` field. As Badger said you might be looking at a different field. If that's not the issue, then another filter might be overriding the value, could you please post the Logstash version you are using and the full pipeline config?